# Getting elevation for multiple lat long coordinates in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have seen the answer to [Elevation info for multiple lat long coordinates](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232130/elevation-info-for-multiple-lat-long-coordinates) and I would like to be able to do this with a python script instead. I cannot use Googles API because I have 8000 points. I have them as part of a .csv file which I import into pandas as a dataframe.

something like:

```py
elevation_list = []

def elevation_function(df):
    for lat,long in zip(df.lat,df.lon):
          elevation_i = some_call_to_file(lat,long)
          elevation_list.append(elevation_i)
```

My coordinates span the western half of the US so Im not sure the function could be so simple. I have downloaded all SRTM90M resolution tiffs [from this amazing person](http://dwtkns.com/srtm/)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/228968/2856

Comment: It isn't quite as simple as this question. I have multiple lat,longs that span multiple tiffs. So first I would need to download all the files. Second I would need to right a function that parses the meta data and chooses that right file to look for each coordinate. I am sure some could make it work but I was not up to the task.  This online method that @Ben Gosak produced is working like a charm.

Comment: You can create a virtual mosiac with`gdalbuildvrt`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't know if this is the simplest way, but it saves gathering elevation data. The USGS-National Map has a REST service that you can use to query elevation for lat/lon coords.

Service url:
https://apps.nationalmap.gov/epqs/ (new)
(old, deprecated as of March 1, 2023: https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/)

You can use pythons requests library and format your query string according to the service parameters. You need your input coordinates in NAD83 (lat/lon).

```
import requests
import urllib
import pandas as pd

# USGS Elevation Point Query Service
#url = r'https://nationalmap.gov/epqs/pqs.php?'
#new 2023:
url = r'https://epqs.nationalmap.gov/v1/json?'

# coordinates with known elevation 
lat = [48.633, 48.733, 45.1947, 45.1962]
lon = [-93.9667, -94.6167, -93.3257, -93.2755]
   
# create data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lat': lat,
    'lon': lon
})

def elevation_function(df, lat_column, lon_column):
    """Query service using lat, lon. add the elevation values as a new column."""
    elevations = []
    for lat, lon in zip(df[lat_column], df[lon_column]):
                
        # define rest query params
        params = {
            'output': 'json',
            'x': lon,
            'y': lat,
            'units': 'Meters'
        }
        
        # format query string and return query value
        result = requests.get((url + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)))
        #elevations.append(result.json()['USGS_Elevation_Point_Query_Service']['Elevation_Query']['Elevation'])
        #new 2023:
        elevations.append(result.json()['value'])

    df['elev_meters'] = elevations

elevation_function(df, 'lat', 'lon')
df.head()
```

Comment: @Bstampe Yes, projecting to web mercator in advance will work. No limit to the number of requests, the process sends a unique request to the service for each coordinate pair. Seemed to be taking about 1-2 seconds per coordinate, so you may want to add a print statement so you know it's running. 5000 refers to spacing between the coordinate values.

Comment: No worries, I would slice off the first 100 points and test with this process to get a better time estimate. I reran with %timit and got:  ~4 sec for 6 records, so you could expect about 1.5 hrs for 8k records.

Comment: Check out the pyproj library for a python solution.

Comment: I have converted from lat lon to utm. how does your function know what zone of utm you are in?

Comment: I see I didn't understand the difference between web mercator and utm. This post has a nice function for converting lat lon to web mercator                                                       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647700/projecting-a-set-of-lat-lon-points-that-spans-on-multiple-utm-zones-into-a-singl

Comment: It doesn't, it's expecting the coordinates as in Web Mercator projection (epsg: 3857), can you project from UTM to Web Mercator?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I have just now gone from lat long to web mercator. That seems like it will do the trick eh?

Comment: yes, it should.

Comment: @Bstampe I found a better service to use, see the edits above. I ran the first service against some known locations, and was also seeing strange results. Although I did not get any NoData returns.

Comment: ! This is working like a charm. Thank you! You saved me another day+ of tooling around USGS sites. I have it running in the background, Ill leave it all night and Ill have what I need! cheers!

Comment: It timed out at 229 seconds. with no response from their server. That seems like an awfully short time to let someone acess gis data...